# Sending audio from client to server

Tags: javascript, java, audio

Im trying to send audio from a client (javascript) to a server (java). I take the user audio from the microphone and then make a blob from it (and a url for the blob). The project is a spring boot project so i am looking for a way to send it as a parameter in a method to upload it to the server.

Was hoping that it would be possible to upload the blob to the server, but it seems to only be avalible localy on the browser and since the url for the blob starts with "blob:" before "http" it causes problems.

I have also looked at serialization but dont seem to find a way to do that with a blob in js.

Just passing the blob url here between the client and the server

Client side in js

```
// Convert the audio data in to blob
                // after stopping the recording
                mediaRecorder.onstop = function (ev) {
                    console.log(dataArray);
                    // blob of type mp3
                    let audioData = new Blob(dataArray,
                        { 'type': 'audio/mp3;' });

                    // After fill up the chunk
                    // array make it empty
                    dataArray = [];

                    // Creating audio url with reference
                    // of created blob named 'audioData'
                    let audioSrc = window.URL
                        .createObjectURL(audioData);
                    //console.log(audioSrc);
                    // Pass the audio url to the 2nd video tag
                    playAudio.src = audioSrc;


                    const url = "http://localhost:8080/speech?url=" + audioSrc;
                    console.log(url);
                    $.get(url, function(data) {
                        $("#resultat").html("transcribed tekst: " + data);
                    });



                }
```

Server in Java

```
@GetMapping("/speech")
    public String speechToText(String url) throws IOException {

        try (SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create()) {
            
            // The path to the audio file to transcribe
            String gcsUri = url;

            // Builds the sync recognize request
            RecognitionConfig config =
                    RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                            .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                            .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                            .build();
            RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder().setUri(gcsUri).build();

            // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
            RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.recognize(config, audio);
            List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

            for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
                // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
                // first (most likely) one here.
                SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
                System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
                return alternative.getTranscript();
            }
            return "idk";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "noe ble feil";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your code?